# Don't allow special characters with DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I have a string property in my ViewModel and I want to set that to don't allow some special characters as , :, *,?, ", <, > and | .
How can I write a regular expression to do it?

Coul be correct *[RegularExpression(@"^[^\/:*<>?|;.)(]+$")]* ?

Comment: What problem are you facing, it's not clear in your post.

Comment: I need to set a string property but not all characters must be valid.
Invalid characters are ^ ? . * < > |  / \ :

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? Can you please post code you've tried and what isn't working with an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem, what *some* special symbols are. If the *complete* list is

```
, :, *,?, ", <, > and |
```

then you can put it as

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^,:*?""<>\|]*$")]
```

if, however, you want to exclude all *punctuation* (`, :, *, ?, "`) and *math* symbols (`<, >, |`), you can put

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\p{P}\p{Sm}]*$")]
```